# Git Push from server (FTP) to Git

Tags: git, ftp, filezilla, git-ftp

I want when I did modification in my files with FileZilla then push it to my branch.

We work right now with Git, everyone has a branch and each one has server FTP the changes are done just local and push it to Git but when we make modifications in FTP (FileZilla) we don't know how to save the work in GIT

Well when we locally push to Git it works fine but when we make a modification in FTP this doesn't save it in Git means after we work in local and push it in Git the modification in FTP is lost

We work in Prestashop and sometimes we give our work to Prestashop teams to do some work they do the work in FTP that's why we need how to save their work before we push in Git in other work we did it

Is it possible to transfer modifications added to my server to git?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to save files that you have uploaded via FTP to Git automatically is not the best idea.  That prevents you from writing good commit messages or handling things like merges effectively.

What is better is to always make the changes in Git and then deploy them using some sort of script to your server.  That way, those changes are already in Git locally and you don't need to worry about adding them after the fact.  The script to deploy them could use a command-line tool to automatically copy them.  This could even be done by a CI system automatically.

Note also that FTP is not really a good protocol for transferring data these days.  Due to a variety of broken implementations, it's nearly impossible to effectively secure it with TLS, which means that anything you upload is likely going to be subject to snooping and tampering.  It's also much less efficient than other protocols and has a variety of cross-platform issues.  SFTP may be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you don't understand what I mean, well I edited my post 
the problem is when I give my work to other teams and when they edit in FTP after that when I push my work to Git, the work in FTP is lost.

Comment: Tell your PrestaShop teams to do work in a copy of your Git repository, or copy it into your repository and then commit and deploy it.  Don't let them push code to your production instance without it going through your source control.  If you are paying someone to work on behalf of your company's projects, you are well within your rights to ask them to use your source control.